# Still stuck in download after uninstalling the app and hard reboot

Tags: downloading

My Android phone (4.4.2) is stuck in downloading an app. I uninstalled the app and removed the battery and rebooted and when it restarts, it's still trying to download the app!

How can I cancel the sticky download?

Comment: Wipe the data of the app called **Download** (or anything alike). If it doesn't suffice, wipe also the **Google Play Store** data.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings->Apps and swipe to display all apps. Find each of the following and Force Stop them THEN clear data for each one:

- Download Manager
- Downloads
- Google Play Store
- Google Services Framework

Reboot after doing this.